# Is it possible to specify the schema for ServiceStack's Auth Feature?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack.Ormlite allows us to use the Schema attribute to decorate database table classes to denote which schema they belong to in the database.

This is great for all tables except, it appears, those created by the Auth Feature.  Is it possible to specify which schema the Auth tables should belong to?  I'd rather not use custom classes purely to decorate with a Schema attribute.

If not, I guess I should request the change somewhere?

**EDIT 1** - following mythz's suggestion

I've added the attribute in my initialisation constructor..

```
public class AuthenticationInitialisation : AppInitialisation
{
    private readonly IAppSettings _appSettings;

    public AuthenticationInitialisation(IAppSettings appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        typeof(UserAuth).AddAttributes(new SchemaAttribute("Admin"));
        typeof(UserAuthDetails).AddAttributes(new SchemaAttribute("Admin"));
        typeof(UserAuthRole).AddAttributes(new SchemaAttribute("Admin"));
    }...
```

I've removed the default schema from my SQL user and am getting an exception on DropAndRecreateTables()...

```
var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)appHost.TryResolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
if (_appSettings.Get("RecreateAuthTables", false))
    authRepo.DropAndReCreateTables(); //Drop and re-create all Auth and registration tables
else...
```

The exception reads

> Cannot drop the table 'UserAuth', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Verified by a SQL Profiler showing the following passed through to SQL Server

```
DROP TABLE "UserAuth"
```

**EDIT 2** - following change to MyGet pre-release ServiceStack version

I am now getting the following error..

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in ServiceStack.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void ServiceStack.MetadataTypesConfig..ctor(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Nullable`1)'.

Stack Trace..

> at ServiceStack.NativeTypesFeature..ctor()
>      at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost..ctor(String serviceName, Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
>      at ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener.HttpListenerBase..ctor(String serviceName, Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
>      at ServiceStack.AppHostHttpListenerBase..ctor(String serviceName, Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
>      at MyProduct.AppHost..ctor(IEnumerable`1 initialisations) in d:\dev\App_Code\AppHost.cs:line 14
>      at MyProduct.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\dev\Global.asax.cs:line 29

on my AppHost Constructor..

```
public AppHost(IEnumerable<IAppInitialisation> initialisations) : base("RESTful Web API", typeof(SystemsService).Assembly)
{
    if (initialisations == null)
    {
        _initialisations = new IAppInitialisation[0];
    }
    else
    {
        _initialisations = initialisations.ToArray();
    }
}
```

If the use of schemas is going into the next ServiceStack release then I'll just wait and set the SQL User's default schema for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the schema attribute to the UserAuth tables dynamically, i.e:

```
typeof(UserAuth)
    .AddAttributes(new SchemaAttribute("MySchema"));

typeof(UserAuthDetails)
    .AddAttributes(new SchemaAttribute("MySchema"));
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @mythz - I've updated the question with the findings of your suggested solution

Comment: @Drammy hmmm looks like I've only expanded Schema's to support Drop/Create table API's recently [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/103c0410c39d3033598e05629c1705decc564e34). Can you try again with the [latest pre-release v4.0.37 on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). Also you'll want to ensure any dynamic attributes are added before any config/initialization of deps that use them.

Comment: thanks for your help @mythz - you must be flat out maintaining a great product whilst supporting the community like you do!  Anyway, if the use of schemas is going into the next release then I'll just wait till that release and set the SQL User's default schema for now..